# hard disk status info with sdparm

Tags: linux, centos7

I have a external hard disk for backups, which is connected over USB with my linux-computer. Because hdparm is not working, I tried to spin down the disk with `sudo sdparm -C stop /dev/sdf1`. How can I find out if the disk is really sleeping now?

Comment: this belongs on [su].

Comment: i update the command to sudo

Comment: no - there is a better stackexchange site for this question.

Comment: Could you give me the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use hdparm, you can use smartctl to collect this information also.

In order to do so, you could run something like:

```
 sudo smartctl  -a  -n sleep /dev/sda
```

You are basically interested in the -n argument, that contains the following documentation.

```
   -n POWERMODE, --nocheck=POWERMODE
          [ATA only] Specifies if smartctl should exit before performing any checks when the device is in a low-power mode. It may be used to  prevent
          a  disk  from being spun-up by smartctl. The power mode is ignored by default.  A nonzero exit status is returned if the device is in one of
          the specified low-power modes (see RETURN VALUES below).

          Note: If this option is used it may also be necessary to specify the device type with the ´-d´ option.  Otherwise the device may spin up due
          to commands issued during device type autodetection.

          The valid arguments to this option are:

          never - check the device always, but print the power mode if ´-i´ is specified.

          sleep - check the device unless it is in SLEEP mode.

          standby  -  check the device unless it is in SLEEP or STANDBY mode.  In these modes most disks are not spinning, so if you want to prevent a
          disk from spinning up, this is probably what you want.

          idle - check the device unless it is in SLEEP, STANDBY or IDLE mode.  In the IDLE state, most disks are still spinning, so this is  probably
          not what you want.
```